# Generation function for binary string

Tags: combinatorics, binary

I am trying to find a generating for the number of binary string with the property that every block of $0$'s of length $ \ge 4$ is followed by a block of $1$'s of length $\ge 4$. I got the following decomposition but my professor says it is wrong. Can somebody tell me why it is wrong and how I can correct it? Thank

$1^*\{01^*,0^21^*,0^31^*,0^40^*1^41^*\}^*$

Comment: Does the notation $a^*$ mean "a string of zero or more instances of $a$"?

Comment: yes. That is correct.

Comment: In that case, I can see a problem: $01^*$ could be just $0$, right? So $\{01^*,...\}^*$ could be an arbitrary number of $0$s, and now you've lost the constraint on the number of $1$s following it.

Comment: makes sense, any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: By adding the condition that at least one $1$ must follow... Instead of $01^*,0^21^*,\dots$ insert an additional $1$ inbetween, $011^*, 0^211^*,\dots$

Comment: then how do I produce $10$?

Comment: How about: $$1^*\{011^*,0^211^*,0^311^*,0^40^*1^41^*\}^*\{\emptyset,0,00,000\}$$ which incorporates @JMoravitz's idea and allows for zero to three 0's at the end. (Are you allowed to use $\emptyset$ like this?)

Comment: I agree with @Théophile (using a slightly different construction). The resultant generating function is $$\frac{1-x^4}{1-(2x-x^5+x^8)}=O(x^{11})+409x^{10} + 211x^9 + 109x^8 + 56x^7 + 29x^6 + 15x^5 + 8x^4 + 4x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1$$

Comment: @Théophile I would rewrite it as $1^*\{011^*,0^211^*,0^311^*,0^40^*1^41^*\}^*(0^*-0^4)$. I think it's correct, thanks

Comment: @scottgreen: Theophile's answer is correct. Yet, $0^*-0^4$ usually means all strings consisting of zero or more $0$'s having length not equal to $4$, which is not the same.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer yes, that was a typo! I meant this:$ 1^*\{011^*,0^211^*,0^311^*,0^40^*1^41^*\}^*(0^*-0^40^*)$

Comment: @scottgreen: Now it is sound (in case the set-minus operator is part of the syntax you use).